# Ubuntu 22.10 not able install mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, mysql, mysql-workbench

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic

I trying

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:

> mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed

> mysql-server-8.0 :
> Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not installable
> Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not installable
> Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not installable
> Recommends: mecab-ipadic-utf8 but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Cache of `apt` on your system have list of Ubuntu 20 packages.

Maybe an `apt-get update` and then `at-get install mysql-server` solve your problem.

Also, It is a good idea to attach the output of your main repositories list `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Maybe you did a manual upgrade!

Comment: but i try 


https://prnt.sc/r-t3OINRebO-

 
 ** How to you /etc/apt/sources.list. Maybe you did a manual upgrade! .

  Please explan ..

Comment: You are using mysql repo and it conflicts with mysql package of ubuntu repo. Temporary disable it: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` and comment all lines. Then `apt update && apt install mysql-server`

Comment: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list 
-----

deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
# deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
Commit this line after trying same issue ,https://prnt.sc/MqbEKCxZkbGN
https://prnt.sc/DgL-JAeTEj4c

Comment: What is the output of `apt search mysql | grep installed` ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/GIEgkbjHyFxG

please check it

Ubuntu version 22.10

Comment: Mistyping! No problem. It's strange that `mysql-common` doesn't exit. It is of `ubuntu-desktop` dependencies.  What if specifically search for that: `apt search mysql-common`